# Extend User authentication object in Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to add additional properties to the User object on the server in WAMS? I would like to store the Id primary key of my User table for (secure) use in my table scripts. At the moment the only id is the vendor specific authentication Id, but I'd like to be able to allow users to choose an authentication method. Currently my (simplified) table design is as follows:

User table:

- id
- googleId
- twitterId
- facebookId
- name, etc...

League table

- id
- userId
- name, etc

I'd like to store the user primary key in the userId field on the league table, and then query it to ensure that users only get to see leagues they created. At the moment, the user object in table scripts sends through a User object with the Google/Twitter/Windows authentication token and I have to do a query to get the primary key userID, everytime I want to carry out an operation on a table with a userId column.

Ideal solution would be that when the Insert script on my User table is called on registrations and logins I can do:

```
// PSEUDO CODE
function insert(item, user, request) {
    var appUserId;
    Query the user table using the user.userId Google/Twitter/Facebook id
    If user exists {
       // Set a persisted appUserId to use in all subsequent table scripts.
       user.appUserId = results.id;
    } else {
         Set the GooTwitFace columns on the user table, from user.userId
         insert the user then get the inserted record id
             // Set a persisted appUserId to use in all subsequent table scripts
            user.appUserId = insertUserPK;
    }
}
```

Then, in subsequent table scripts, I'd like to use `user.appUserId` in queries

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is authorize users to only have access to their own data, I'm not sure you even need the "user" table. Just use the provider-specific userId on the user object to query your "league" table (making sure the userId column is indexed). The values will be provider-specific, but that shouldn't make any difference.

If you are trying to maintain a notion of a single user identity across the user's Google/Facebook/Twitter logins, that's a more complicated problem where you would need a "user" table and the kind of lookup you are describing. We hope to ship support for this scenario as a feature out of the box. It is possible (but fairly messy) to do this yourself, let me know if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Yavor, 1 user ID with multiple providers is what I'm trying to do. I guess another way of solving my problem would maybe be a session object?